# Доступ к Ui из другого класса

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать так,что бы из класса `test` можно было менять индекс `comboBox`.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
     Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
     void on_pushButton_clicked()
           test *t = new test();


};
extern MainWindow *Main;
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
#include"mainwindow.h"

test::test()
{
//Main=new MainWindow;//тоже не работает
Main->ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(2);
}
```

Пробовал и без `extern`,не хочет работать.Может есть у кого простой пример как можно реализовать подобный способ(`Main->ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(2)`)?

В `builder` он работает(`extern PACKAGE TCalcForm *CalcForm;`),а в `Qt5` не получается.

Comment: Передавайте указатель на MainWindow в конструктор test. test тоже создавайте в конструкторе MainWindow

Comment: А если без создания обьекта `test`?

Comment: Тут вы его создаете `test *t = new test();`, разве нет? Просто сделайте `test *t` полем `MainWindow`, а в конструкторе создайте передав текущий объект MainWindow в конструктор `t = new test(this);`, плюс, не забудьте вызвать для `t` удаление в деструкторе `MainWindow`

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь получить в конечном итоге? Замешивая такое взаимодействие объектов вы ничего хорошего не получите в конечном итоге.